# Operação matemática com dois aliases Oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Boa tarde pessoal!
Tenho uma dúvida que pode parecer fácil, mas não encontrei a resposta.

Nesse exemplo, fiz duas funções CASE e inseri um alias para cada uma. Eu quero fazer uma simples operação para criar uma nova coluna entre o resultado desses dois aliases, sem ter que escrever toda a função novamente.

O que eu esperava era isso: `HORAS_PRODUTIVAS + HORAS_IMPRODUTIVAS` , mas não funciona.

Como eu "converto" essas funções para se tornarem o nome da coluna, e assim poder fazer cálculos com outras colunas do select?

Segue meu select:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN AOS.CD_HISTORICO = 10 
       THEN ROUND(TEMPO_APONTADO_SEGUNDOS / 3600, 3)
       END as HORAS_PRODUTIVAS
,CASE WHEN AOS.CD_HISTORICO <> 10 
       THEN ROUND(TEMPO_APONTADO_SEGUNDOS / 3600, 3)
       END as HORAS_IMPRODUTIVAS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que você pode utilizar uma tabela derivada ou uma CTE conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
WITH CTE_CASES AS
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN AOS.CD_HISTORICO = 10 
            THEN ROUND(TEMPO_APONTADO_SEGUNDOS / 3600, 3)
        END as HORAS_PRODUTIVAS,
        CASE WHEN AOS.CD_HISTORICO <> 10 
            THEN ROUND(TEMPO_APONTADO_SEGUNDOS / 3600, 3)
        END as HORAS_IMPRODUTIVAS
    FROM TABELA
)

SELECT
    HORAS_PRODUTIVAS,
    HORAS_IMPRODUTIVAS,
    HORAS_PRODUTIVAS + HORAS_IMPRODUTIVAS
FROM CTE_CASES
```

Comment: Muito obrigado de novo @imex !! Consegui usar o with e adaptar meu código